# Using Magento as backend ONLY for website

Tags: backend, code, licensing

I want to use my own frontend for my website, and only use Magento for the cart and backend. Most of the site is not a commerce site and I don't want Magento taking it all over. I've read about how to do this with Zen Cart, and I was wondering if it's feasible to do with Magento as I much prefer Magento's backend.

Basically I want to figure out how Magento adds items to the cart and use that code in a button on my website while using my own theme. Then I want to use the code that displays the cart and allows you to checkout in another page.

I'm not even sure this is allowed with Magento's licensing.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to rustle something up using [Magento's SOAP / RESTful API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) depending on your version of Magento and with some off the cuff PHP.

There is a project which I've never used personally which uses a Angular JS + Laravel "Frontend / Store View" and Magento to power the ecommerce side of things: [Magento On Angular](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Magento-on-Angular)